# Is it possible to change an image of ImageView dynamically?

Tags: android

This my java code how I implemented.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int count=0;
            while (true) {
                if(count>5)
                    count=0;
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   System.out.println(""+e);
                }

                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slider);
                image.setImageResource(pics[count]);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

I have created a separate `Thread` to change the images dynamically

Comment: Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for accessing `ImageView` from other Thread

Comment: Don't start new threads unless you mean it, use threadpools via [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) but not even that is required for this simple task. Never start a task or thread just to delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you're trying to set a picture from thread different than UI thread. And you're only allowed to change the UI from the UI thread.

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slider);
image.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                image.setImageResource(pics[count]);
            });
```

This will post your changes into the UI thread's queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the Handler's `postDelayed` method

```
 public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private boolean exit = false;
    public MyRunnable(ImageView n) {
        imageView = n;
    }  

    private void setExit() {
        exit = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (exit) {
            imageView.removeCallbacks(null);
            imageView = null;
            return;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(pics[count++%5]);
        imageView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}
```

Declare a member:

```
 MyRunnable mRunnable = null;
```

onResume

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slider);
 image.postDelayed(mRunnable = new MyRunnable(image), 1000);
```

and onPause call

```
 mRunnable.setExit();
```

Comment: Maybe that `onCreate` code could be in `onResume`, and in `onPause` call the `setExit`?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could put your image in Drawable and then use

> ImageView.setImageResource (int resId)

Didn't tried but should work fine

Comment: your answer is usefull just like mine ,